# Typings: Type declaration for JS module exporting instance of class, with prototype of the class

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

*I'm sorry if the title is confusing, I'm not entirely sure how to phrase it better.*

I'm trying to wrap my head around writing type declarations by attempting to produce one for [this file](https://github.com/kristofferostlund/tiny-eventer/blob/master/tiny-eventer.js) (which is the source for [this npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-eventer)), wherein I basically export an instance of the `Eventer` class allowing the module to as a singleton but also contains a property referencing the class to create sandboxed instances. I'm using Visual Studio Code to check if the properties are correct. The module looks something like this:

```
// tiny-eventer.js

function Eventer () {
    this.on = function (eventName, listener) { ... };
    this.trigger = function (eventName, args) { ... };
}

Eventer.prototype.Eventer = Eventer;

module.exports = new Eventer();
```

In another module I can then use the singleton-like `eventer` instance by requiring it, but also create a sandboxed instance calling `new eventer.Eventer()`.

```
// index.js

var eventer = require('tiny-eventer');

var sandboxedEventer = new eventer.Eventer();

sandboxedEventer.on('an-event', function (args) { console.log('sandboxed ' + args); });

eventer.on('an-event', function (args) { console.log('global ' + args); });

eventer.trigger('an-event', 'is called');
// Prints to console: "global is called"

sandboxedEventer.trigger('an-event', 'is called');
// Prints to console: "sandboxed is called"
```

This basically means this horrific piece of code is valid too:

```
// sorry.js

var eventer = require('tiny-eventer');
var otherEventer = new (new (new (new eventer.Eventer()).Eventer()).Eventer()).Eventer();
```

As for the typings I've tried the following:

```
declare module 'tiny-eventer' {
    ...

    interface TinyEventItem { listener: (args) => void }

    class Eventer {
        // Doesn't seem to work as it should
        Eventer: Eventer;

        on(eventName: String, listener: (args) => void): TinyEventItem;

        trigger(eventName: string, args: any): void;
    }

    export = new Eventer;
}
```

The above will work with the singleton properts such as `eventer.on` and `eventer.trigger`, but also seems to allow `eventer.Eventer.on`, whereby `new eventer.Eventer()` isn't allowed. It feels like I'm doing this wrong.

How would I got about writing a typings file which declares a class with a property referencing itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out something that produces the result I'm looking for (in vscode's Intellisense at least), although I'm not sure it's a proper solution.

What solved it for me was the following `Eventer: new Eventer;`

If anyone has a *better* solution, please post them or update this.

```
declare module 'tiny-eventer' {
    ...

    interface TinyEventItem { listener: (args) => void }

    class Eventer {
        on(eventName: String, listener: (args) => void): TinyEventItem;

        trigger(eventName: string, args: any): void;

        // This right here seems to do it
        Eventer: new Eventer;
    }

    export = new Eventer;
}
```